# Who are the characters present in Justice League: Crisis on Infinite Earths?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

Who are all the characters present in the movie Justice League: Crisis on Infinite Earth (Part  One). I have attached the images of characters to be identified.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm reasonably sure that's The Flash

Comment: I've identified most characters (all but two or three, I think). If you got any doubt about the ones that I haven't located in a specific image, just comment below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have numbered the characters in the two more crowded pictures. I haven't watched the movie so I can't identify special characters just develop for the film (25?).

[image: Numbered characters]

0. [Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(Mar_Novu))
1. [Elongated Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_Man)
2. [Doll Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doll_Man)
3. [Solovar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovar)
4. [Wildcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcat_(Ted_Grant))
5. [Flash (Jay Garrick)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(Jay_Garrick))
6. [Dr.Fate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Fate)
7. ?
8. [Metal Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Men) (from left to right: Mercury, Iron, Gold)
9. [Captain Marvel Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_Jr.)
10. [Speedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedy_(DC_Comics))
11. [Black Canary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Canary)
12. [Mary Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Marvel)
13. [Uncle Marvel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Marvel)
14. [Hawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hank_Hall)
15. [Peacemaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peacemaker_(character))
16. [Dove (Dawn Granger)](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Dawn_Granger_(New_Earth))
17. [Hawkgirl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkgirl)
18. [Challengers of the Unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challengers_of_the_Unknown)
19. [Blackhawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhawk_(DC_Comics))
20. [Negative Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentina_Vostok)
21. [Nighthawk](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Hannibal_Hawkes_(New_Earth))
22. [The Ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_(Ray_Terrill))
23. [Mento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mento_(character))
24. [Obsidian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsidian_(character))
25. [Dawnstar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawnstar) ?
26. [Harbinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harbinger_(DC_Comics)) ?
27. [Starman (Ted Knight)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starman_(Ted_Knight))
28. [Black Lightning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Lightning)
29. [The Creeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creeper_(DC_Comics))
30. [Jade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jade_(DC_Comics))
31. [Blue Devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Devil_(DC_Comics))
32. [Dr. Mid-Nite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Mid-Nite)
33. [Mr. Terrific (Michael Holt)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Terrific_(character))
34. [Robin (Tim Drake)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Drake) (According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_Crisis_on_Infinite_Earths_%E2%80%93_Part_One), he may be [Robin from Earth 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_(Earth-Two)) instead)
35. [Blue Beetle (Ted Kord)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Beetle)
36. [Green Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Arrow)
37. [Phantom Lady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_Lady)
38. [Katana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katana_(DC_Comics))
39. [Swamp Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp_Thing)
40. [Aquaman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquaman)

[image: Second numbered panel]

1. Elongated Man
2. Mento
3. Peacemaker
4. [Thunderer](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Thunderer_(Earth_7))
5. ?
6. Negative Woman
7. [Star Sapphire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carol_Ferris)
8. [The Flash (Barry Allen?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(Barry_Allen))
9. [Black Condor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Condor)
10. Obsidian
11. [Firestorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestorm_(character))
12. [Tomahawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomahawk_(character)) ?
13. Doll Man
14. Mr. Terrific (Michael Holt)
15. [Green Lantern (John Steward)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Stewart_(character))
16. Green Arrow
17. [Captain Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Atom)
18. [Zatanna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zatanna)
19. [Uncle Sam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Sam_(comics))

In the other pictures you can find: [Metamorpho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorpho), [Red Tornado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Tornado), [Huntress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntress_(DC_Comics)), [Aqualad/Tempest](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garth_(DC_Comics)), [Amazing-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazing-Man_(DC_Comics)), [Batgirl (Barbara Gordon)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batgirl), [The Question (Vic Sage)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_(character)), Batman, [Red Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Star_(comics)), [NightShade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightshade_(DC_Comics)), [Doctor Light (Kimiyo_Hoshi)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Light_(Kimiyo_Hoshi)), and a Batman variant/allied that I can't fully identify (bright blue bat in the chest) ([Batwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batwing_%28DC_Comics%29)?).

Comment: I was uncertain on some of the same ones you were, but I also was guessing Dawnstar, Harbinger, Tomahawk

Comment: @DaveCosta I added Dawnstar because she's listed in the voice cast [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League:_Crisis_on_Infinite_Earths_%E2%80%93_Part_One) Don't know what happened with her wings. :-(